# Can I change float value from x to y in a specified time?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am a beginner C# Unity coder and i need help. So i want to change a float value from x to y in specified time (to raise the x value proportionally with the time to y). I have a body that moves forward, and when i press a key i want it to slow for 5 seconds and than return to it's initial speed, but not instantly!

```cs
public float forwardForce = 20;
float slowDelay = 5;

void update()
{
    if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
    {
        forwardForce = 5; //Here i want to slow it from 20 to 5 in specified time
        Invoke("AfterSlowDelay", slowDelay);
    }
}

public void AfterSlowDelay()
{
    forwardForce = 20; // Here i want to return to his initial speed from 5 to 20 in a specified time
}
```

Comment: Mathf.Lerp or Mathf.MoveTowards are the two methods you want to look into. There are much detailed explanation over the internet, sometimes with Vector3 but it works just the same (probably dozens of them and tutorials). Maybe someone who wants karma will write another one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Inside `Update()` function you can get a delta time between your current update call and previous update call. So you can count seconds with it (this code is untested, but should work):

```
public const float NormalForwardForce = 20.0f;
public const float SlowForwardForce = 5.0f;

public float currentForwardForce = 20.0f;

public const float MaxSlowMotionDurationSec = 5.0f;

bool isSlowMotion = false;
float slowMotionDurationSec = 0.0f;

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown("e"))
   {
       isSlowMotion = true; // starting slow motion
       currentForwardForce = SlowForwardForce;
   } else if (isSlowMotion) { // if slow motion, then count up to 5 sec
       slowMotionDurationSec += Time.deltaTime; // counting time
       if (slowMotionDurationSec > MaxSlowMotionDurationSec ) { // 5 sec exceeded
           isSlowMotion= false; // ending slow motion
           slowDurationSec = 0.0f; // reseting slow motion counter
           currentForwardForce = normalForwardForce;
       } 
   }
}
```

**EDIT (again, untested):** for smooth transition, you would use `Mathf.Lerp` and another variable `float SlowMotionTransitionSec = 2.0f;` for a number of seconds of smooth transition.

```
public const float NormalForwardForce = 20.0f;
public const float SlowForwardForce = 5.0f;

public float currentForwardForce = 20.0f;

public const float MaxSlowMotionDurationSec = 5.0f;

public const float SlowMotionTransitionSec = 2.0f; // number of seconds for transition

bool isSlowMotion = false;
float slowMotionDurationSec = 0.0f; 

void Update()
{
   if (Input.GetKeyDown("e")) {
       isSlowMotion = true; // starting slow motion
   }
   if (isSlowMotion) { // if slow motion, then count up to 5 sec
       slowMotionDurationSec += Time.deltaTime; // counting time
       
       // value between 0 and 1, where 0 is for normal speed
       // and 1 is for slow motion speed
       float transitionTheta = 0.0f;
       if (slowMotionDurationSec <= SlowMotionTransitionSec) {
           // slow motion beginning transition
           transitionTheta = slowMotionDurationSec / SlowMotionTransitionSec; 
       } else if (MaxSlowMotionDurationSec - slowMotionDurationSec <= SlowMotionTransitionSec) {
           // slow motion ending transition
           transitionTheta = (MaxSlowMotionDurationSec - slowMotionDurationSec) / SlowMotionTransitionSec; 
       } 
       currentForwardForce = Mathf.Lerp(NormalForwardForce, SlowForwardForce, transitionTheta); // setting smooth force
       if (slowMotionDurationSec > MaxSlowMotionDurationSec ) {
           // end of slow motion
           isSlowMotion= false; // ending slow motion
           slowDurationSec = 0.0f; // reseting slow motion counter
           currentForwardForce = normalForwardForce;
       } 
   }
}
```

Comment: This does not work exactly how i wanted to. But definitely smoother than my code, and i really like it.

Comment: @HircaRazvan how did you want it exactly? A smooth transition?

Comment: Yes, I want a smooth transition from 20f 5f. And i was thinking ,as i asked, to make the transition in 2 seconds for example. like when i pressed down e it should be 20f first frame and with every frame or millisecond to raise down and at sec 2 to be 5f. If i was understandable. (as the guy above he said to use `mathf.lerp` or `mathf.moveTowards` but i have tried it before and it didn't worked so well, or maybe i didn't used them correctly, If this may help you)

Comment: @HircaRazvan check the edit, you can change the number of seconds for transition

Comment: This works exactly how i wanted to, but i also want this transition as it returns to it's normal speed.(i have tried to do it myself but it didn't work..)

Comment: @HircaRazvan check the same edit, but as code becomes more complex, you might have some performance issues if there're many slow motioned objects. So if you have any performance drops, then you'll have to think of a better solution than mine (the simple one)